# Node-Red Watson "Unauthorized access" but API key field is filled

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, personality-insights, watson-personality-insights

I've been trying to use node red to work with watson personality insight. So far so good, I've created an account in IBM Watson Cloud and I generated a new lite project on personality insight.

My problem is in node red, when I put my API key on it it says it's unauthorized. I'm not too sure if I have to put my username and password too, I've tried all of them but nothing seems to work.

[image: Unauthorized Access]

Comment: Have you bound the service instance to the Node-RED app in the console?

Comment: @hardillb No I don't think I did, what do you mean by that? Thanks!

Comment: You do it in the IBM Cloud console, it tells IBM Cloud you want to use the service instance with the app and it will include the credentials and connection details to the environment variables passed to the app (node-red)

Answer (score 0):

Binding the service will allow the node  to discover the credentials. What you are most likely missing is the endpoint, which you have as the default. I am guessing your service instance is not on the default of US South.